# Not seeing the connections network Updates from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

Through LinkedIn API, if I query for network updates, generally I see all the update types - CONN, VIRL, CMPY, etc.

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/network-update-types

However, only for certain users, CONN updates dont show up. For them I see other update types, just the connections oens are not available.

Do we know why? What are we missing? Or are those few users doing something specific with their permissions. We tried a few combinations, but still cannot figure it out.

Thanks,
Kushal.